# Tradução da notificação de usuário confiável

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Na notificação de atribuição do privilégio de [usuário confiável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) falta traduzir "access 'trusted user' tools":

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Proponho a tradução:

> acesso a ferramentas de 'usuário confiável'